# Google Plus face tagging of non G+ user

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-photos, google-plus-tags

I'm playing with the tag-people feature in G+ photos; in particular, I want it to automatically tag photos of my son (who doesn't have a G+ account), and then be able to show all the photos of him. Is this possible? I seem to be able to tag him, but can't find any way to view photos sorted by who's in them (apart from myself).

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? I'm having the same problem, but I can't seem to figure out how to do facial tagging of a non-G+ user. It doesn't allow you to free text enter a person's name, it requires they have a Google account. This doesn't work for kids who don't have accounts and/or other friends/relatives that you want to tag in order to easily search and find pics.